# Argument of type '{ year: number; month: number; date: number; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'DateObjectUnits'

Tags: javascript, typescript, momentjs, moment-timezone, luxon

I am getting this error in my vscode when I hover my code:

```
Argument of type '{ year: number; month: number; date: number; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'DateObjectUnits'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'date' does not exist in type 'DateObjectUnits'.ts(2345)
```

Here my logic was created in moment library where my dates are not ok in moment and I am receiving output which my code sample is given below,

```
// Moment:

const date = '';

const start = moment(date[0]).set({
  year: moment(date[0]).get('year'),
  month: moment(date[0]).get('month'),
  date: moment(date[0]).get('date'),
});

console.log(`This start moment Method : `, start);
```

**Here is the output:
**

**`This start moment Method : 2022-12-02T09:53:35.724Z`**

But when I am trying to convert this into luxon here I am not getting expected output which I am getting in Moment, here is my code sample,

```
// Luxon:

const date1 = '';

const start1 = luxon.DateTime.fromJSDate(date1[0]).set({
  year: luxon.DateTime.fromJSDate(date1[0]).get('year'),
  month: luxon.DateTime.fromJSDate(date1[0]).get('month'),
  date: luxon.DateTime.fromJSDate(date1[0]).get('date'),
});

console.log(`This start luxon Method : `, start1);
```

**Here is the output:
**

**`This start luxon Method : null`**

I am receiving null in luxon as like moment I want same output `// 2022-12-02T09:53:35.724Z`

**Expected output similar should be like moment: **

**`This start luxon Method : 2022-12-02T09:53:35.724Z`**

Comment: Could you provide a link to typescript playground with an example?

Comment: The error says that ts is not expecting the field `date`, how is `DateObjectUnits` defined?

Comment: `'date' does not exist in type 'DateObjectUnits'` -  did you mean `day`?

Comment: Hello @Nullndr this is the code editor: https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-w2chm6?file=index.js

Comment: @Nullndr above the link you can get the example sample of the code and check in the console.

Comment: Here I am confused @Nullndr is my luxon converting is correct?

Comment: No @Konrad i am converting moment into luxon but i am confused is my format is ok: https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-w2chm6?file=index.js

Comment: Why do you use `.fromJSDate(date1[0])`? `date1` is an empty string, a not a js date

Comment: In this case @Konrad what you suggest me to use: can you check my code sample: https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-w2chm6?file=index.js and help me what can i correctly use this in luxon.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do because your moment code is equivalent to `moment()`,  because you are just creating current date. In luxon it would be `luxon.DateTime.utc()` or `luxon.DateTime.now()`

Comment: Yes it is ok if it is current date no problem @Konrad

Comment: But @Konrad I am trying this but still i ma receiving null: ```const start2 = luxon.DateTime.fromISO(date1[0]).set({
  year: luxon.DateTime.now(date1[0]).get('year'),
  month: luxon.DateTime.now(date1[0]).get('month'),
  date: luxon.DateTime.now(date1[0]).get('date'),
});```

Comment: `const start1 = luxon.DateTime.utc();` https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-7gwkou?file=index.js

Comment: I think @Konrad the method is wroking now ```const date2 = '';

const start2 = luxon.DateTime.now(date2[0]).set({
  year: luxon.DateTime.now(date2[0]).get('year'),
  month: luxon.DateTime.now(date2[0]).get('month'),
  date: luxon.DateTime.now(date2[0]).get('date'),
});

console.log(`This start luxon Method : `, start2);

const date3 = '';

const start3 = luxon.DateTime.utc(date3[0]).set({
  year: luxon.DateTime.utc(date3[0]).get('year'),
  month: luxon.DateTime.utc(date3[0]).get('month'),
  date: luxon.DateTime.utc(date3[0]).get('date'),
});```

Comment: This is the output same as moment I am getting ```This start2 luxon Method :
2022-12-02T10:35:46.056+00:00
This start3 luxon Method :
2022-12-02T10:35:46.056Z```

Comment: I still don't get it why you use this `date2[0]` it's literally `undefined`. You are also setting the same year, month and date again

Comment: Hello @Konrad ```date[2]``` is (parameter) date: any in my code for dateChangeHandler property.

Comment: It is define as like const date4 = [new Date()]; @Konrad

Comment: Thank you very much @Konrad for our help I am getting now expected output.

Answer (score 1):

```
const start1 = luxon.DateTime.fromJSDate(date1[0]).set({
  year: luxon.DateTime.fromJSDate(date1[0]).get('year'),
  month: luxon.DateTime.fromJSDate(date1[0]).get('month'),
  day: date1[0].getDay(),
});
```

The `.set` method does not accept a field named `date`, in order to set the date you have to set `day` ecc.

Check [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-6Te4nMSq8P2qPMF0er3av03Sp3WQPdNpCqhnMRzL5mPKIsJkvJsvUP57QHkjXgyHQ2GI5Gokl8MOY7FMglEi0c8muGTiTCYRVgADq8DImVArqEADcRCxt9BkElUtgAIT95BCaDQUpkA+61KwFjiD6IFOILw4L8AELoOAqTlve0A7NwZDyJU4FPge1SgIGkzCA+8G0GQMiFPAAASCJREqupwgAPHgHIAHweqA7rjpk8DEcAZHkXC3AAiQQA)

Comment: Hello @Nullndr Here i am converting this logic moment into luxon not the date method, my moment method i am getting expected output but in luxon I am receiving null .

Comment: I need this into luxon logic.

Comment: This day: date1[0].getDay() is causing more errors: Error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getDay')

Comment: This simply means that the array is empty